# Blocking behaviour in node-mysql

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I'm playing with node.js and node-mysql and I'd like to understand the following:

```
connection.connect(function(err) { if (err) throw err; });
console.log(" beginn insert "+ Date() );
for (var i=0;i<200;i++){
  connection.query('INSERT INTO animals SET ?', {name: "tiger!"});
}
connection.end();
console.log(" end insert " + Date() );
```

The output is always ' beginn insert ' immediately followed by ' end insert ' and then only the database starts working. How is it possible that these node-mysql statements seem to be non-blocking?

Thanks, Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Async; something like the following:

```
console.log(" beginning insert "+ Date() );
// create your queries as an array of objects
queries = [];
for (var i=0;i<200;i++){
  queries.push({name: "tiger!"});
};


async.map(queries, myQuery, function(err, data){
    // Here all of your queries are done
    connection.end();
    console.log(" end insert " + Date() );
});

function myQuery(name, callback){
    connection.query('INSERT INTO animals SET ?', [name], function(err, result) {
      if(err){
        console.error(err);
        callback(err, null);
      }else{
        callback(null, result);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Good idea with this async-module, but I don't get it to work with node-mysql. queries.push({'INSERT INTO ...'}); is throwing a SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: If I only use an array of strings like > array [ 'INSERT INTO animals SET name = \'anakonda\'', 'INSERT INTO animals SET name = \'biber\'' ] in combination with async.each() node-mysql throws an Error: Object #<Object> has no method '_implyConnect' at Connection.query

Comment: while connection.query(array[1],function(err){}); works fine.

Comment: It works like magic. I'm trying to understand what's going on. Please correct me if I got something wrong: async.map calls myQuery with the anonymous function(err, data) as callback. myQuery is called once for every item in the array "queries"; the current item is passed to myQuery as the parameter "name". If no error occurs the callback function(err, data) is called once with an array of all the 200 results it got from connection.query.

Comment: @Kiechlus Correct! You got it!

Answer (score 2):

Node itself is non-blocking for IO so queries such as these do not block.  Instead you need to pass a callback function when the query completes:

```
var queries = 0;
connection.query("INSERT INTO animals SET ?", {name: "tiger!"},
function (err) {
    // handle error?
    queries++;
    if (queries == 200) {
        // Last query has finished running
    }
});
```